# Filter pandas dataframe based on different dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating an initial df from a csv file like the following:

```
knobs_df = pd.read_csv(knobs_container)
        name     type                                             values
0  algorithm   string                                      one;two;three
1    threads  int32_t                1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15
```

For every row I extract into `k_values` and `k_type` the type column and the values column as dictionaries.

```
    k_values = {}
    k_types = {}
    for row in knobs_df.itertuples(index=False):
        k_values[row[0]] = row[2].split(';')
        k_types[row[0]] = row[1]

{'algorithm': ['one', 'two', 'three'], 'threads': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15']}
{'algorithm': 'string', 'threads': 'int32_t'}
```

From the `k_values` dictionary I generate a full grid containing all the possible combinations.

```
   algorithm threads
0        one       1
1        two       1
2      three       1
3        one       2
4        two       2
..       ...     ...
88       two      14
89     three      14
90       one      15
91       two      15
92     three      15
```

Having a list of constraints (Python expressions) like the following

```
['threads < 20', 'algorithm != "two"']
```

I'd like to filter the full-grid dataframe using the `query` method from `pandas.DataFrame`. Is there a way to assign each column with its coresponding dtype based on the `k_types` dictionary? I need to do this because every column has potentially an independent type and, for instance, the query method fails in filtering the 'threads' column since all columns are inferred by default to 'str' during creation. Problem is that since the types are C++ datatypes originally, I don't know if there's a way to achieve this.

Possible k_types are:

```
[string, short int, int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t, uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t, char, int, long int, long long int, int_fast8_t, int_fast16_t, int_fast32_t, int_fast64_t, int_least8_t, int_least_16_t, int_least32_t, int_least64_t, unsigned short int, unsigned char, unsigned int, unsigned long int, unsigned long long int, uint_fast8_t, uint_fast16_t, uint_fast32_t, uint_fast64_t, uint_least8_t, uint_least16_t, uint_least32_t, uint_least64_t, intmax_t, intptr_t, uintmax_t, uintptr_t, float, double, long double]
```

Comment: You know you can explicitly set the dtypes of a column after you create the dataframe, there are plenty of example of how to do this on SO.

Comment: @adirabargil if you are asking about all possible types I can provide a list but they are basically all possible C/C++ types. What I'm trying to figure out is if it is possible to infer the type from a C/C++ type. I'm aware that we can force/specify a dtype with pandas. Maybe I expressed myself wrong with the question, I can create a new one if that's an issue.

Comment: There, I've provided all possible k_types I can expect.

Comment: I'm thinking about making something like a `convert_type` method that given one of the following types return the corresponding Python type based on the built-ins of the standard (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

Comment: please look into the answer and let me know if it fits

Answer (score 0):

i managed to find an incomplete solution due to some misunderstanding. please let me know how to make this solution fit your needs:

```
t_df = df.T
names = t_df.loc['name']
dtypes = t_df.loc['type']
t_df.columns =  names
t_df = t_df.iloc[2:]
dtype_conv = {'string':str,'int32_t':int}
for dtype,name in zip(dtypes,names):
    t_df[name] = t_df[name].str.split(';')
    t_df=t_df.explode(name)
    t_df[name]  =t_df[name].astype(dtype_conv[dtype])
t_df.sort_values('threads').reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
algorithm   threads
0   one     1
1   two     1
2   three   1
3   one     2
4   two     2
5   three   2
6   one     3
7   two     3
...
```